# Known risks with the old IPSEC Cisco VPN client?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, cisco

I have a couple of customers who still use the old [discontinued/obsolete](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/obsolete/security/cisco-vpn-client.html) IPSEC based Cisco VPN client.

Obviously it is not a good idea to use software that is no longer supported, but that aside: what are the known risks with this client app, the hardware backing it, and the tunnel tech itself? I have been looking for CVEs, but haven't found anything 'interesting' yet.

I have recommended that they upgrade to something more modern (and supported), but I would like to have concrete examples of what problems and risks are associated with it, and be able to provide my customers with some real reasons why they should upgrade to use e.g. AnyConnect instead of the old vpn client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell what problems a specific unsupported software will cause in detail. But, if you look at the [list of past CVE for this product](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/1887/Cisco-Vpn-Client.html?vendor_id=16) you'll see regular problems  and even problems reported after the product was already [end of life](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/vpn-client/end_of_life_c51-680819.html). This can be used as a base to extrapolate what kind of problems might still be lurking in the software.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am thinking too. However, my dilemma is: how do I convince them that it is time to replace this old/unsupported tech with something new/supported/maintained? Maybe this is just a shortcoming in my communication skills, but maybe someone else has been through this already?

Comment: @KristoferA Run through some compromise scenarios based on the previous vulnerabilities, the implication being there is evidence to suggest these could recur in the future.

Comment: The several hours wasted into troubleshooting a connection error after a software/appliance update or when trying to join a new node to a network might be able to help convince them.